# Compiling flash fla project without flash ide

Tags: flash, compilation, flashdevelop, apache-flex

I am fairly new to actionscript but have quickly got sick of the flash IDE, so I have switched FlashDevelop which I like already.

The problem I have now is that FlashDevelop still switches to Flash to compile the fla.
This wouldnt be too much of an issue but the compile takes 30s + each time, which is a real pain for debugging.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: 30s+ seconds??? :o I think you are low at resources. Also keep the flash IDE open. Alternative for the problem is to use the opensource flex framework.

Comment: @loxxy: Yes 30 seconds plus... there dev machine has plenty of free resource... so it is possible to compile the fla outside flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using assets in the .fla? Try creating a swc file with the library assets and then compiling directly in Flash Develop (http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3:FlexAndFlashCS3Workflow)

You may need to change your project type to an AS3 Project rather than a Flash IDE one.

Comment: Thanks. I am using assets and will give this a try

Answer (score 1):

Remember to include the SWC completely if you are going to use getDefinitionByName with definitions stored in the SWC

See here: http://flashontherocks.com/2010/12/13/flashdevelop-resolved-issues/